# how instanceof operator working in overriding of equls() method

Tags: java

I want to know how instanceof operator is working in overriding of equals() method
In this example how "obj instanceof FooForEqual" is returns "true" in overridden equals(). Can anybody explain?

```
public class EqualsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        FooForEqual ffe1=new FooForEqual(23);
        FooForEqual ffe2=new FooForEqual(23);
        if (ffe1.equals(ffe2)) 
        {
            System.out.println("both objects are equal");
        }
        else
            System.out.println("both objects are not equal");
    }
}

class FooForEqual
{
    private int fooForEqualValue;
    public FooForEqual(int number) {this.fooForEqualValue=number;}

    public int getFooForEqualValue() {
        return fooForEqualValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        if (obj instanceof FooForEqual && (  ((FooForEqual) obj).getFooForEqualValue()==this.fooForEqualValue)) {
            return true;
    }
     else 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? You don't understand the use of `instanceof` or something? I found the code quite obvious.

Answer (score 0):

`obj instanceof FooForEqual` would return true if you are passing an instance of `FooForEqual` (or a sub-class of `FooForEqual`) as an argument to the `equals` method.

It means that one of the conditions for an object to be equal to an instance of the `FooForEqual` class is being an instance of `FooForEqual`.

After `obj instanceof FooForEqual` is evaluated to `true`, the `equals` method can safely cast `obj` to `FooForEqual` and further compare the properties of the two `FooForEqual` instances to determine equality.